# Swaping values of a column in SQLite3 using UPDATE

Tags: database, sqlite

As title says, how can I swap all the values of a column that can be 'A' or 'B', making all columns with 'A' have a 'B' and all columns with a 'B' have an A?

I'm not sure how if making it with UPDATE and SET will change all the A's into B's and then, when all the columns have a 'B', they will change into As.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` like this:

```
update tablename
set col =
  case col 
    when 'A' then 'B'
    when 'B' then 'A'
  end   
where col in ('A', 'B')
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9zZ7HCAnEQxvsTYzjQ14F6/0).